# Xamarin.Forms not working in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms app in Visual Studio using Visual Studio Online Team Explorer. But whenever I try to build my main project or iOS project I get the following error:

> /Users/test/Visual Studio/workspace/MyProject.iOS/MyProject.iOS.csproj(5,5): Error: This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ../../packages/Xamarin.Forms.2.5.1.444934/build/netstandard1.0/Xamarin.Forms.props. (MyProject.iOS)

I tired looking for the NuGet store but couldn't find it on the mac version. It is already installed on my windows laptop that also uses it.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio for Mac, you can manipulate your packages using the Project menu. In your case, you'll want to use Project|Restore NuGet Packages.

Comment: I tried but I am still getting errors everywhere on the Mac when I open it on my Windows it works fine.